# How to use the Python API of TensorFlow from within a .NET/C# project?

Tags: python, .net, tensorflow, c#-4.0

TensorFlow's C API doesn't provide the full functionality, but the Python API does. So what I am looking for is a way to access the Python API from a .NET solution, written preferably in C#. I am not the biggest Python crack around, but I am willing to learn just enough to write appropriate wrappers.

The easiest way, at least to my rookie eyes, seems to be to grab the whole TensorFlow Python code, stuff it (somehow...) into a CPython / IronPython project, create the neccessary assemblies, et voilà... But I guess it is not that easy, because of the many C API wrappers for .NET around.

Answer (score 0):

We are making a free-for-noncommercial use wrapper, currently in tech preview: https://github.com/losttech/Gradient-Samples